# ChartsJS Not loading except with Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ChartsJS to create a gauge. I like their styles so I thought it wouldn't be too hard to implement compared to Highcharts or others.

I put the code (which comes in from a jQuery AJAX load - might be a factor) and it ONLY works if I right click and open Inspect Element, or if it is already open, I have to close it. Otherwise it's just empty white space ... no console errors..

Code:

```
var scaleSettings = {
startValue: -50,
endValue: 50,
majorTick: {
    color: 'black',
    tickInterval: 10
},
minorTick: {
    visible: true,
    color: 'black',
    tickInterval: 1
}
};


 $("#gaugeGraph").dxCircularGauge({
    value:200,
    valueIndicator: {
        type: 'rangebar',
        color: '#483D8B'
        },
        geometry: {
    startAngle: 180, endAngle: 0
},
scale: {
    startValue: 0, endValue: 100,
    majorTick: {
        tickInterval: 25,
        tickInterval: 50,
        tickInterval: 75,
        tickInterval: 100
    },
    label: {
        customizeText: function (arg) {
            return arg.valueText + ' %';
        }
    }
}
});
```

Load Code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    loadURL("dataGraph.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>", $('#section > .graph'));
    loadURL("dataGauge.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>", $('#section > .gauge')); //GAUGE

                $(window).trigger('resize'); 

    loadURL("dataRecords.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>", $('#section > .dataTable'));
```

});

Comment: Are you sure it's connected to the dev tools? Did you try resizing the browser window? Maybe your code is connected to a change event somewhere.

Comment: YES - i just resized it and it worked ...

Comment: @k0pernikus do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Quick hack could be to manually trigger a resize event `$(window).trigger('resize')` at the end of your ajax load success handler.

Comment: just add that line of code exactly?

Comment: Basically, yes. Just make sure it runs at the very end of the whole ChartJs-bit. If you are unsure how to proceed at the part of how you do the ajax load to your question.

Comment: I added it in ... it's still not working.

Comment: I added the code above

Comment: Try putting the $(window).trigger('resize'); at the very end of the $(document).ready()-function.

Answer (score 0):

@k0pernikus helped to discover the resize issue.

I used this code to make it happen:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var scaleSettings = {
startValue: -50,
endValue: 50,
majorTick: {
    color: 'black',
    tickInterval: 10
},
minorTick: {
    visible: true,
    color: 'black',
    tickInterval: 1
}
};

 $(window).resize(function()
{
     $("#gaugeGraph").dxCircularGauge({
    value:200,
    valueIndicator: {
        type: 'rangebar',
        color: '#483D8B'
        },
        geometry: {
    startAngle: 180, endAngle: 0
},
scale: {
    startValue: 0, endValue: 100,
    majorTick: {
        tickInterval: 25,
        tickInterval: 50,
        tickInterval: 75,
        tickInterval: 100
    },
    label: {
        customizeText: function (arg) {
            return arg.valueText + ' %';
        }
    }
}
});
}).resize();





});
```